# Unable to get the node value using xpath in camel

Tags: xpath, apache-camel

I am trying to extract a node value from an input xml in camel and below are the sample xml and sample route that i have.

```
<root>
    <jobs>
          <job id="1">Salesman</job>
          <job id="2">Manager</job>
    </jobs>
</root>
```

Here i want to fetch the 1st job which is Salesman.

Route

```
from("file:src/data?noop=true")
.setHeader("someHeader",xpath("/root/jobs/job"))
.to(someCustomComponent://foo);
```

When i retrieve the header, iam getting an instance of DTMNodeList from which i need to extract the node value after iterating.

Iam expecting the value to be retrieved as string. How do i do that?

Thanks.

Regards
Senthil Kumar Sekar

Answer (score 4):

Use [`stringResult`](http://camel.apache.org/maven/current/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/builder/xml/XPathBuilder.html#stringResult()):

```
from("file:src/data?noop=true")
  .setHeader("someHeader",xpath("/root/jobs/job").stringResult())
  .to(someCustomComponent://foo);
```

This will give you "Salesman" simply because the definition of "string value" of a set of more than one node in XPath 1.0 is the value of the first node in the set in document order. But you might want to use a more specific path to ensure you're pulling out the right thing, e.g. `/root/jobs/job[@id='1']`

Answer (score 0):

try `/root/jobs/job/text()` in the xpath

Comment: That'll still give you a node set, just one containing text nodes instead of element nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following xpath: string-join(/root/jobs/job, ',') . That will give a comma separated string of the node values.